# Flex/Java project page not redirecting, hashtag on end of url

Tags: apache-flex, redirect, flex3

I have a Flex/Java project and when i click in a link inside the html on the application, it changes the browser url to the new url but the page dont redirect to the link, but if i go to the browser url bar and press enter, it redirects correctly. If i open the link in a blank page, it works too.

project url: https://myapp.application.com/#

redirected url: https://myapp.application.com/#contentId=123&versionId=123

Why it isnt redirecting just with the click on link?

It has a "#" (hashtag) at the end of URL, What is this "#"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **deep linking**. Parameters after **#** symbol actually represent the state of your application, and changing them does not mean changing the url. This mechanism allows you to manage states of your application and enables history. Use [BrowserManager](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deep_linking_3.html) class to cope with these parameters.

You can also read about [deep linking](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deep_linking_2.html).